# How to animate the HTML5 number counter in Arabic

Tags: html, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-animate, css-animations

Trying to animate the number counter animation for a client. When I did this 2 years ago, the client missed the fact that the numbers were not animated in Arabic (since I couldn't find a way to do this on a deadline) They now want the new website to have animated numbers. How would I do that? The counter scrips I see online only work on English numbers.

[With number animation](https://www.grouporigin.com/clients/dxb/ar18/)
[Without number animation](https://www.grouporigin.com/clients/dxb/ar18/ar/index.html)

Any help would be appreciated please.